# How to unwrap UV for curved mesh correctly? (Making curved conveyor belt)

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm trying to create a curved conveyor belt. What I wanted to do was to unwrap and straighten the UV for the belt so that in the game shader I could just create a belt animation by offsetting texture position on Y axis. For some reason, the texture is not stretched correctly on the mesh. Any idea why it projects texture like that? Or I'm grossly misunderstanding how this supposed to work?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the triangles that are inside your quads deform the image, you need to add topology to your mesh, see the difference between left and right topologies:

[image]

Here if I draw the line that separates the 2 tris that make your quad:

[image]

Another solution, 2 objects, you rotate the image on the circular one while you just move it on the straight one (quickly made). Maybe you can make this solution compatible with your game engine?

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That worked for me. There is still some distortion left unless I add a lot more subdivisions. 

Is there a way to reduce distortion without having high poly topology? Seems a bit inefficient if I were to use this for a game.

Comment: maybe in that case you need to find a completely different solution? like some objects animated in loop, but I don't know if it would be lighter...

Comment: actually you could separate the 2 parts (the straight and the circular) and create 2 animations, in the circular part use a circular image that you simply rotate? Seems like a good solution. See my edit

Comment: Finally had time to get back to it. Thanks for the second suggestion that worked really well. Here is the result https://i.postimg.cc/26XhyWtK/Belt.png

And as for the animation, it looks butter smooth now. I made a shader that just rotates the UV.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the feedback  ;)